# Angular form validation ng-disabled not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, validation

I am trying to use the angular form validations in my form for a blog post, and more specifically a ng-disabled form. For reasons I cannot figure out the submit button is not disabled, where as it should be unless all three input fields are valid. Thanks for the help.

this is my blog template

```
 <div ng-controller='BlgoCtrl'>
  <div class='container'>
    <h1> Teewinot Blgo</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-md-12'>
        <form role='form' name='blgoPost' novalidate>
          <div class='form-group'>
          <label for='blgoTitle'>Title</label>
          <input name='title' type="title" class='form-control'  placeholder='Technologies of the Future' required><br>
          <label for='blgoContent'>Content</label>
          <textarea name='content' rows='8' type="content" class='form-control' placeholder='The technical innovations of the future will be diverse and impactful on the individual......' required></textarea><br>
          <label for='blgoPassCode'>PassCode</label>
          <input name='passcode' type="passcode" class='form-control' placeholder='&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;' required><br>
          <button type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' ng-disabled="blgoPost.$invalid">Submit Post</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Teewinot</title>

  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <link href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body ng-app="Teewinot">
<ng-include src="'app/templates/partials/navbar.html'"></ng-include>

<ng-view></ng-view> 
<!-- angular module defintion and reoutes -->
<script src="app/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/routes.js"></script>
<!-- controllers -->
<script src="app/js/controllers/blog.controller.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my blog controller

```
angular.module('Teewinot').controller('BlgoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  'use strict'
});
```

Comment: And where is your code that sets the $invalid value ?

Comment: Instantiate the module as `angular.module('Teewinot', [])`. Pass an empty array to the module function. And, also use `ng-model` for each input.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're missing `ng-model` on every field of your form. Keep in mind when you mention `ng-model` on any form field at that time `ng-model` creates the extra objects inside form name object with that specific `name` attribute which then considered while form validation like `$error`, `$valid`, `$invalid`, etc.

As your form `name` is `blgoPost`, when angular compile this page,it internally creates the object inside the scope of the name of `blgoPost`. And the all the input fields which has `name` & `ng-model` assign to them gets added inside that `blgoPost` object. But if you don't mention `ng-model` to the form fields then it will never get added inside the `blgoPost` form object.

**HTML**

```
<form role='form' name='blgoPost' novalidate="">
    <input name="first" />
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for='blgoTitle'>Title</label>
        <input name='title' type="title" class='form-control' ng-model="test1" placeholder='Technologies of the Future' required="">
        <br>
        <label for='blgoContent'>Content</label>
        <textarea name='content' rows='8' type="content" ng-model="test2" class='form-control' placeholder='The technical innovations of the future will be diverse and impactful on the individual......' required=""></textarea>
        <br>
        <label for='blgoPassCode'>PassCode</label>
        <input name='passcode' type="passcode" ng-model="test3" class='form-control' placeholder='&#8226;&#8226;&#8226' required="" />
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' ng-disabled="blgoPost.$invalid">Submit Post</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13291/)