# Why do we need ng-model in ng-form?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-form

Why do we need ng-model in ng-form? It does not work properly without it
This is example from ng book

```
<form name="forma" ng-submit="cliker()" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="filed in fields" ng-form="ngforma">
        <input  type="text" 
                name="nameOfInput" 
                placeholder="{{filed.placeholder}}"
                ng-model="field.name"
                ng-required="filed.isRequired"/>
    <div ng-show="ngforma.nameOfInput.$dirty && ngforma.nameOfInput.$invalid">Error</div>
    </div>
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="forma.$invalid">Submit All</button>
</form>


</body>

<script>
    angular.module("APP", [])
        .controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
            $scope.fields = [
                {placeholder: "placeholder", isRequired: "true"},
                {placeholder: "placeholder", isRequired: "true"},
                {placeholder: "placeholder", isRequired: "false"}
            ],

            $scope.cliker = function(){
                alert("Yes")
            }

        })  
</script>
```

It works without ng-model but then ng-disabled does not work. I can even put some random text inside of ng-model so it will work.

Comment: its working as expected here is plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/6RaUuwk4PldDKSwdOUNb?p=preview

Comment: Yes, it works, but if you will delete ng-model its not gonna be validating correctly. Not sure why

Comment: I don;t understand properly what you want? but `ng-disabled` is working correctly

Comment: No, if you will delete ng-model and run code in plnk, you will see that button "Submit All" is always enabled.

Comment: That is how angular form work..unless you add `ng-model` to those fields, they wouldn't be considered as a part of form..thats why ng-disabled is always getting true.. look at this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28569650/2435473 Also I'm going to mark this question as duplicate

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Do look at that answer..if you don;t understand anything..ask me..and do upvote that answer..if that does help..

Comment: Its a great answer, helped me a lot. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you..Thanks :)