# Simple submit form using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, bind, angularjs-forms

I'm new to Angular, but very old with google.

I cannot find out how to submit this form using Angular, like how we do in jQuery.

```
<form>
   <input type="text" />
   <button type="button" class="saveDraft">Save Draft</button>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
<form>
```

I want to submit this form from a save draft button, but not a normal submit button.

jQuery we use

```
$('.saveDraft').click(function () {
    $('form').submit(); // this will submit form 
});
```

Comment: may I know why you wanted to do in this way.are you going to do custom validation inside that `click` function?

Comment: Yes, I want to set hidden value before submitting form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could have `ng-submit` directive on `form`, When you click on submit button it call the method mentioned in `ng-submit` directive.

**Markup**

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
   <input name="name" type="text" ng-model="name"/>
   <button>Save Draft</button>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
<form>
```

Read here for [**how form work in AngularJS?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28569650/2435473)

**Update 1**

If you wanted to perform validation of button `click` but making its type as `button` itself would be some thing look like below using `ng-click` directive

**Markup**

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
   <input name="name" type="text" ng-model="name"/>
   <button type="button" ng-click="manualSubmit()">Save Draft</button>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
<form>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.manualSubmit = function(){
   //do your the process of adding hidden fields.
   //then submit a form
   //if you don't want to submit on some cases then put it in condition block
   $('form').submit(); // this will submit form 
}
```

> But technically I wouldn't prefer to do this approach as using jQuery with make
>   problem Angular digest cycle.

If you really wanted to add `hidden` field inside a form, so I would keep them on `form` itself rather than adding them dynamically before submitting a form. And will use `ng-submit` directive.

For filling up those hidden values you could use `ng-value` directive with scope  variable in it. What that `ng-value` directive will do is, it will update the those hidden field, suppose `scopeVariable` value is changed from controller will update the hidden field value.

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
   <input name="name" type="text" ng-model="name"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="somehiddenfield" ng-value="scopeVariable"/>
   <button>Save Draft</button>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
<form>
```

**Update 2**

As per comment you wanted to submit a form manually using angular, for that you could have directive in place which will submit a `form`. You don't need ng-submit in such case.

**Markup**

```
<button type="button" my-submit="callback()">Save Draft</button>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('mySubmit', function(){
  return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.on('click', function(event){
            //do stuff before submitting
            element.parent.submit(); //manually submitting form using angular
            if(attrs.callback)
               scope.$eval(attrs.callback);
        })
     }
  }
})
```

[**Update 2 Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/fMxDrM5nu2G9s1IsPL9X?p=preview)

Comment: @Basit when you don't mention a `type` attribute on `button` by default its considered as `submit`, however when you click on `Save Draft` it will submit out the for with the input fields

Comment: I have removed down vote.  but $('form').submit() is using jQuery and I dont want to include jquery library just to submit form. cant we do this from angular? I just need to set $scope.draft = 1; and submit form..

Comment: @Basit what exactly the `submit()` is going to do..I don't seem any `action` attribute on your `form` so that wouldn't make any difference..basically it will only fire `submit` event

Comment: I have huge form, which I cant paste here to confuse people. thats why I kept it small and simple. normal submit will show the values to public, but if user wants to save as draft, then he will click on the link or normal button, which will change the value and submit the form. I'm still confused on how to submit form from a function using angular.

Comment: @Basit look at my update..what you said in your second last comment..you need to set `$scope.draft = 1`?

Comment: I was testing your directive and it is giving this error "formCtrl.submit is not a function"

Comment: @Basit try edited..make sure `require: '^form',` is there & link function has `formCtrl` parameter in 4th place

Comment: @Basit apology..I thought there is submitEvent inside `ngFormController`, but there is no such, you need to trigger the event manually by calling `submit` event on that DOM using jQuery..

Comment: well Thank you for trying. maybe click on submit button from draft button, will solve this?

Comment: I have 10+ scripts loading already, I dont want to add jquery as well. the script is using jquery, which I'm avoiding to use :)

Comment: Thank you for helping out. I have voted up too. but simple pure javascript did the job thanks to Adjit -on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508617/jquery-submit-replacement-with-angular#33508617

Comment: I dont prefer that. Because you went for selector..which is i afraid of..adding selector inside directive would make it specific that dom..sould have that selector..

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter text and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  <pre>list={{list}}</pre>
</form>
```

And documentation:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Comment: sorry, this  does not answer the question I was asking

Answer (score 0):

you just replace you code with this

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()" action=" name of other page" autocomplete="on">`
```

`<input name="name" type="text" ng-model="name"/>
   <button onClick="draft(this.form)">Save Draft</button>
   <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>`

Comment: sorry, but how can this submit form from save draft button type=button?

Comment: you can pass the current form object like this....
<button onClick="draft(this.form)">Save Draft</button>

Comment: the question is how to submit form from normal button or a link.