# jQuery .submit() replacement with angular?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, forms, form-submit

Is there angular event trigger function, like we have with jQuery for following action?

```
$('.link').click(function () {
    $('form').submit(); // this will submit form 
});
```

Please note, that this is not onSubmit function which is mostly `<form ng-submit="submit()"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-click` to call a function in your controller to execute form submission.

```
$('form').submit()
```

using jQuery

or

```
document.getElementById('someForm').submit()
```

using JavaScript

Comment: @Basit glad it worked out for you. Just be careful of multiple submit buttons inside a form (if you have them)