# Email validation in angular js

Tags: angularjs

i am learning angular from w3schoot. i stumple to understand a code like how it is working. code taken from http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_model.asp

```
<form ng-app="" name="myForm">
    Email:
    <input type="email" name="myAddress" ng-model="text">
    <span ng-show="myForm.myAddress.$error.email">Not a valid e-mail address</span>
</form>
```

what is the meaning of **ng-model="text"** ? basically i have see we write like `ng-model="Name"` etc but here we use text....why ?

from where this comes `$error.email` ? help me to understand this. thanks

Comment: Honestly...[this would be a better place](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) to look up what these things mean in forms.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28569650/2435473) might help you with from where `$error` object comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ng-model="text"
```

Declares a variable in the DOM which binds this "text" to the current scope. So whatever email is entered into that form the value of it will be accessible in the variable text. So you could access it in angular.js file with:

```
$scope.text
```

In relation to why we use text: It is just the name of the variable so it is arbitrary. For example you could call it emailText.

Comment: $error is a reference to a built in validation token. So it is checking the input field of name myAddress of form myForm of type email to see if it is a valid email address. See: [This link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

Comment: I have entered `demo@test`, without any domain .. it's shows valid email .. Look Here >> http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_model_validate