# How to validate forms in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-forms

i'm a newbie in angular JS. and i was trying the input `type="text"`, i'm retrieving my name from my controller and i was using `$dirty` and `$invalid` to validate my data but it isn't showing when i make the input field empty.

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/24718/

```
var FormValidations = angular.module('FormValidations',[]);

FormValidations.controller('FormsValidations', function( $scope ){

    $scope.formsToBeValidated = {
        firstName : 'Daniel'
    };


});
```

Comment: why don't you use ng-messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you add `name` attribute to form level field, that will not get included in form object when you specified in the `name` attribute on `form`, currentlyh it is `name="studentForm"`. Do add `name="firstName"` to your input field

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
  name="firstName" ng-model="formsToBeValidated.firstName" required/>
```

[**Forked Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nmvjeeuc/)

For more information you could refer [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28569650/2435473), which has more detailed

---

More convenient way to solve this issue would be using `ng-messages` instead of using `ng-show`/`ng-hide`, for that you have to include `ng-messages` module with its `ng-messages` dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the help ... name attribute was missing.

Comment: @Daniel do go through the link which I've added in answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you should try this:

```
      <input name="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" 
ng-model="formsToBeValidated.firstName" required>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aznj2as7/)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified name to your input. Try this:

```
<form name="studentForm" novalidate>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name ="input" ng-model="formsToBeValidated.firstName" required>
    <span studentForm.input.$error.required && studentForm.input.$dirty>First Name is Required</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

as other says , add "name" attribute to your input.

I made a custom directive to display error on input using ng-message ( so you have to include it )

```
directives.directive('inputerrormsg', function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        plain: true,
        scope: {
            inputdata: "=",
            dpattern: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="help-block has-error text-center" ng-messages="inputdata[\'$error\']" >' +
        '<p ng-message="required">{{\'The field is required\'| translate }}</p>' +
        '<p ng-message="minlength">{{\'Input too short\'| translate }}</p>' +
        '<p ng-message="maxlength">{{\'Input too long\'| translate }}</p>' +
        '<p ng-message="email">{{\'Email invalid\'| translate }}</p>' +
        '<p ng-message="date">{{\'Date invalid\'| translate }}</p>' +
        '<p ng-message="number">{{\'Write number only\'| translate }}</p>' +
        '<p ng-message="pattern">' +
        '<span ng-switch="dpattern">' +
           '<span ng-switch-when="date">{{\'Date incorrecte: YYYY, YYYY/MM, YYYY/MM/DD\' |translate}}</span>' +
        '<span ng-switch-default>{{\'Saisir uniquement des lettres\'| translate }}</span>' +
        '</span>' +
        '</p>' +
        '</div>'
    }
});
```

USAGE :

required field

```
<div style="padding-left: 0px;" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : !formDeter.scientificname.$valid">
<div class="input-group no-padding">
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control input-md" name="scientificname"
           required />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<dir.inputerrormsg inputdata="formDeter.scientificname" ></dir.inputerrormsg>
```

EMail :

```
<div class="form-group row" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : !formData.email.$valid }">
    <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">{{"Email" | translate }}</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8 input-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="email" name="email" id="email" required
               placeholder="{{'Email' | translate }}"/>
    </div>
    <dir.inputerrormsg inputdata="formData.email" dpattern="email" ></dir.inputerrormsg>
</div>
```

Number only :

```
 <div class="form-group row" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : !formLocalisation.decimallongitude.$valid }">
    <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">{{"Longitude" | translate }}</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8 input-group">
        <input type="number" popover-trigger="focus" placeholder="{{'Longitude' | translate }}"
               class="form-control input-md" 
               ng-model="specimen.decimallongitude" name="decimallongitude"
                />
        <span class="input-group-addon" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <dir.inputerrormsg inputdata="formLocalisation.decimallongitude" ></dir.inputerrormsg>
</div>
```

...