# Why does an AngularJS form post sometimes have one parameter empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http-post, angular-http

I have a quite large AngularJS application and one of the forms is giving me trouble.  On this form users can write messages that are saved on the server into the database.  However, 20% of the time, some kind of error is causing the message to be blank.  I can see these empty messages in the database.

As far as I can tell the problem is happening on the client not the server.  (My evidence for this is that I've added code on the server that logs all the form data the moment that the web request is received.  When blank messages are saved into the database, I can see that the message text was already missing in these logs right at the start of the server-side process.)

So, I think it may be something to do with the way I send the data from the client.  My JavaScript is as follows...

```
var params = {
    "slotid": self.slot.slotid,
    "personid": self.personid,
    "message": self.slot.message
};

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/restapi/confirmationmessage.aspx',
    data: $.param(params),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
})
```

When it works, the form data on the server looks like this:-

```
slotid=SOME-GUID8&personid=ANOTHER-GUID&message=the+message+goes+here
```

When it fails it looks like this:-

```
slotid=SOME-GUID8&personid=ANOTHER-GUID&message=
```

The web page that accepts the message input is written using Bootstrap and the relevant fragment is below.  The submit button is disabled if the textarea box is empty, so blank messages shouldn't ever happen!

```
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="slot.message" placeholder="Enter your message here..." rows="8"></textarea>
</div>
<button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.areyousure('message', slot, '');" ng-disabled="slot.message==''" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope">&nbsp;</span>
    <span>Send message</span>
</button>
```

In case it helps, my back-end is written in ASP.NET using C#.

Can anyone explain why the message parameter is sometimes empty?  It is an intermittent fault, so I think it might have something to do with unusual characters in the message, but I've tried, commas, quotes, double quotes, and semi-colons, but they all worked fine.  Could it be a limitation in the function $.param()?

It would also be useful to get some suggestions about how I could add some logging to my client-side code to help diagnose the problem, or any similar idea to help me solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your initial value for slot.message will be either null or undefined, so you should add those cases as well.

But this is not the right way checking for required value. You should use ng-required attribute, here is an example of using form-ng-required [Angular form validation ng-disabled not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568962/angular-form-validation-ng-disabled-not-working)

Comment: My JavaScript initialises slot.message to an empty string, so null and undefined are prevented.

Comment: ... and I'll add in ng-required.  But do you have any ideas about the problem I'm having?

Comment: can you provide any example when it fails,you can also replace this line     data: $.param(params),
with     params: params,

Comment: No I can't provide any example of when it fails.  My server doesn't receive a value for the message parameter, so I'm unable to share it with you.  That's the problem.  If i don't use $.params() then the serialisation will be different.  I'm not sure that back-end will still work without changing it.  Are you saying that you wouldn't expect $.params() to work?

Comment: without example its hard to say, but you should be using params, because that is what angularjs $http provides for this scenario, what you are doing seems unconventional https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

Comment: thanks.  Can you be clear about what I should change to make it more conventional?

Comment: replace "data: $.param(params)", with "params: params"

Comment: Thanks.  I've made the change you've suggested.  Let's see if it fixes it.  I'll have to wait for the users to show some more activity to see if any more problems occur.  I'll report back.

Comment: About ten days ago I made this change

replace "data: $.param(params)", with "params: params"

and also strengthened the logic in the form to ensure that the user could not leave the input box blank.  Since then I have not had a single message come through with a bank message,  So I am accepting this answer.

Thanks!