# angular: form not submitting data not showing in firebug

Tags: angularjs

I have a form and in that from there are some text boxes. Textbox are generated at run time. Like user can add or remove text boxes.

Here is the form.

```
<form name="formprofile3" method="post" id="formprofile3" role="form" ng-submit="formprofile3()">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

                   <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                      <textarea name="exp_details" ng-model="choice.name" class="form-control textbox1" id="exp_details" placeholder="Experience" required="required" rows="3"></textarea></div>
                      <div class="col-xs-2">
<button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
</div>       
</fieldset>
<button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">+</button>

                   <div id="choicesDisplay">
                      {{ choices }}
                   </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
<center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-home" name="btn-save1" id="btn-save1" required="required">Save & Finish <i class="icon ion-arrow-right-a"></i></button></center>
</form>
```

here is the angular code to submit the form.

```
formApp.controller('formProfile3', function($scope,$http){

      $scope.formData = {};

        $scope.formprofile3 = function() {


          var allData={'formData': $scope.formData, 'uid': uid}
        $http({
              method  : 'POST',
              url     :  'add_profile.php',
              data : allData,
              headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  
          })
              .success(function(data) {
                   if (!data.success) {

                      $scope.message = data.errors.message;

                  }else{
                      alert('Your details has been updated.');
                             }

              });

      };

    })
```

Problem is when i submit the form. It is not getting submit. no data is getting in post.

Any advise what am i doing wrong.

Edit: i can see the data in {{ choices }}.

**Choices are not coming in formdata.**

Here is the data in firebug.

```
{"formData":{},"uid":"75"}:""
```

Comment: They are in the inner scope created by `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` inside the form

Comment: is there anyway i can use that while form submit.

Comment: Why did you added `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` here: `<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">` ? As @PankajParkar wrote in his answer, this is the issue,  but there's not enough context in the question to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `ng-app` & `ng-controller` directives to `body`/`html` tag, so that `form` & `ng-submit` directive should get compile

```
<body ng-app="angularjs-starter" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="formprofile3" method="post" id="formprofile3" role="form" ng-submit="formprofile3()">
        ....
    </form>
</body>
```

Also I can't see any `formData`(as ng-model) two way binding is present there on page. I guess you should look for `choices`. Additionally add `name` attribute to each `textarea` field to it part of form object for validation purpose.

Comment: how can i add name attribute to textarea. is that by angular if yes then how? i am learning angular.

Comment: @CalculatingMachine checkout [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28569650/2435473), you will get clear about how form work